# Doubts about the SL 5X5 program

Tags: stronglifts

This week I started doing the StrongLifts 5X5 program but I already have some questions regarding 2 situations. I know posting 2 questions is not very well received but I'd hate to post 2 questions back to back about the same program.

- What happens if I reach a limit? Like I fear I will reach my overhead press limit in around 3 weeks(doing the math and based on past maxes) while still being able to increment the weight for squats and dead lifts. Can I just stay in that weight til I overcome it?
- The program suggests resting between workout a and workout b for a day, but that would leave me Saturday and Sunday free, I used to rest these days but I used to workout out 5 days a week, with only 3 days a week of routine is it okay if I plan to do something less intense than weightlifting(jogging, walking, core exercises) during one of these days?

Comment: If you say you used to work out 5 days a week, what exactly did you do? SL 5x5 is a beginner program, are you sure it's still suitable for you?

Comment: I didn't know it was only for beginners, but the "build real strength" part really caught my attention and although I used to workout I'm still a bit overweight so I thought I could benefit from the program @G_H

Comment: If you feel you could still make linear progression, go for it. That's the hallmark of a novice. Same if you haven't worked out in quite a while. But otherwise you might do better on an intermediate program.

Comment: Fyi The first question is clearly addressed in the 5x5 documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**What happens if I reach a limit?**

[What if I fail to get 5 reps](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/#What_if_I_fail_to_get_5_reps)

[What if I keep failing at the same weight](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/#What_if_I_keep_failing_at_the_same_weight)

You will probably reach your 5x5 limit on OHP quickly, the program tells you to deload and move to 3x5 after 3-4 sessions of failure. The website has all the information on deloading. Essentially though, yes, you will reach a point of doing the same weight while your other lifts increase. I maxed out my 1x5 deadlift at 135kg and squat at 100kg but my 1x5 OHP had stalled and stopped weeks before.

**Can I exercise on rest days?**

Mehdi advices not to exercise on rest days. Once the weights get towards your 1RM you will absolutely need those days to rest.

I just graduated off the programme and am very happy with my noob gains and progress on my form. I feel stronger as a result and would recommend it again, that is for sure.

Comment: Useful links from the site. Missing reps: http://stronglifts.com/5x5/#What_if_I_fail_to_get_5_reps. Deload protocol: http://stronglifts.com/5x5/#What_if_I_keep_failing_at_the_same_weight. And moving to 3 sets or even less eventually. And yes, respect the rest days.